# Replace part of Python array with NaN

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to replace part of my array (let's say 10% of length of a given array) with NaNs. I know that if I wanted to replace only particular values (e.g. bigger than 255), I can do it using `arr[arr > 255] = np.NaN`. But what if I want the replaced values to be selected randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is this what you trying:**

```
import numpy as np
import random

an_array = np.array([5, 6, 7,2,4,5,6,7,8,9])
an_array = an_array.astype("float")

percent_len = round(len(an_array) * 10 / 100)
print(f'percent len : {percent_len}')
index_visited = []

print('Before:')
print(an_array)

for i in range(percent_len):
    while True:
        some_index = random.randint(0,percent_len)
        if some_index in index_visited:
            continue
        else:
            index_visited.append(some_index)
            break
    
    an_array[some_index] = np.nan

print()
print('After:')
print(an_array)
```

**result:**

[image]